# What is the difference between these two versions of code in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

What is the difference between the code in Junit:

```
class MethodsTest {
    Methods methods = new Methods();
}
```

and these:

```
class MethodsTest {

    Methods methods;
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        methods = new Methods();
    }
}
```

When to use first code and when to use second code?

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, you hope that the particular test runner you're using is creating a new instance of `MethodsTest` implicitly creating a new instance of `Methods` when executing a particluar test. In the second version, you're telling the test runner you're using explicitly to create a new instance of `Methods` when executing a new test.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no inheritance involved, there is no difference.

If you were to extend the `MethodsTest` class, you could override the `init()` method, and the overriding method would not necessarily either initialize the field directly, or perhaps indirectly by invoking `super.init()`; or it could initialize it differently.

Personally, I would prefer the first. It's more concise, not overrideable, and its semantics are obvious to anybody familiar with Java, even without JUnit-specific knowledge.